# WPF Datagrid - child datagrid populates when clicked on toggle button (+/-) of parent datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, parent-child, rowdetailstemplate

I am a new member to this forum, glad to be part of it :)

I need help with **parent-child datagrid** (both containing same rows but data called from different tables). The parent datagrid should have a button or a plus-minus symbol with each record which when clicked should open child datagrid and display the related records of that row.

Please see one screenshot of requirement below, when clicked on record 147, the child grid expands and shows related records.

- BNo Date          Status    Amount
  147 1/31/2014   Complete    2300
      BNo Date          Status    Amount
      147 1/31/2014    Complete    2300
      147 1/20/2014    In Process  2300
      147 1/1/2014     New         2300
- BNo Date          Status    Amount
  140 3/1/2014    Complete    6900

Sorry, I don't have much points to post this image hence copy-paste it :(

The parent datagrid have to populated from sql db (Master_TBL) and for child datagrid separate table (HISTORY_TBL) of same db to be used.

Can someone please guide me with some examples or provide me some good links for this. Please bear with my lack of knowledge in WPF, this is my first WPF project.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/678985/Parent-Child-Grid-in-wpf can refer as it is showing you the whole xaml code for implementing above

Comment: Thanks Ashok. This example got textblock inside datagrid while I am need datagrid inside datagrid, Not sure how to populte the childgrid on clicking on row button.

Comment: You better study the RowDetailsTemplate of Wpf Datagrid and Google for Examples for same. If you had concept in hand then you will get better Idea